# How to add the account?

Tags: disqus

Now, I have one in Google account. I have one in Disqus account based on that Google Account. Moreover, there are two more Google accounts.

At the same time, it is possible to increase two accounts of Disqus?

How about can I use non-Google mail service account?

Answer (score 1):

Two years [ssəๅʞɹoɟ Mod •](https://disqus.com/home/channel/discussdisqus/discussion/channel-discussdisqus/multiple_accounts/) wrote:

> You are allowed to have and use multiple accounts, what is a violation of the ToS though is using them to skirt sanctions that were put in place or use them for automated scripts such as voting bots.

Comment: >to skirt sanctions that were put in place
Is it to post with more than two accounts on one bulletin board?